# create dynamic schema in mongo database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, lrs

How to assign the dynamic data in mongo db json object

```
{
"actor" : {"mbox" : "mailto:tom@example.com"},
"verb" : {"id" : "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/answered",
          "display" : {"en-US" : "answered"}},
"object" : {"id" : "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/question"}
};
```

In my json object the display value comes dynamically how can i assign that.

I pass this json values to the xapi and my local mongo db.

Comment: Can you make it more clear? You want to create this data from the code?

Comment: I want to pass this json to my xapi but i get the display value dynamically so i don't know how to assign dynamic value in mongo db.